# Visual Studio extension disable command

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I have created an extension on visual studio 2019, the extension contains 1 command, so far so good the extension is working perfectly. 
I want to improve my extension by disabling or enable (or show and hide) the menu item associated with the command depending on the type of selected items
Since I’m using the new version of the studio my package class inherits from AsyncPackage, at the moment I have tried to wire the OnChange event on the InitializeAsync method but the event does not trigger also I tried to use the same code on the InitializeAsync method of my command and the result is the same it never triggers

```
    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken,
                                                  IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        // When initialized asynchronously, the current thread may be a background thread at this point.
        // Do any initialization that requires the UI thread after switching to the UI thread.
        await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);
        await ExampleCommand.InitializeAsync(this);

        _dte2 = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;

        _dteEvents = _dte2.Events as Events2;
        _selectionEvents = _dteEvents.SelectionEvents;
        _selectionEvents.OnChange += SelectionEventsOnOnChange;
    }

    DTE2 _dte2;
    Events2 _dteEvents;
    SelectionEvents _selectionEvents;

    void SelectionEventsOnOnChange()
    {
        //This method never triggers
    }
```

I have also tried to an OleMenuCommand and use the event BeforeQueryStatus but it also never trigger, here is the code I'm using for the OleMenuCommand

```
  ExampleCommand(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService)
    {
        this.package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
        commandService = commandService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandService));

        global::System.ComponentModel.Design.CommandID menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
        menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(Execute, menuCommandID);
        menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus += MenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus;
        commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
    }
    void MenuItem_BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleMenuCommand myCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;
        if (null != myCommand)
        {
            myCommand.Text = "New Text";
        }
    }
```

you can find a full copy of the project in my github 
https://github.com/egarim/DisableCommandMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to hide or show menu items is by using visibility constraints as shown in their sample extensions repository here [VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/VisibilityConstraints)

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag> to your button command in .vsct.